# What's the best way to inject JavaScript into Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to generate PDFs. In a large SPA, there are quite a few times when the code references `window`, but `window is not defined` is often what I see in practice.

If I run the code within the context of Puppeteer, then it should be okay as a headless browser should have a `window` property.

I've seen the approach of having the SPA in a separate port and opening that port, but I'm not sure if that is the best approach to the problem as I already know the JavaScript that I want to run and I just want it executed within the context of Puppeteer.

Is there a better way to execute JavaScript in Puppeteer? Perhaps using something like `puppeteer.setContent('<script>...</script>')`?

If the separate port option is the best I have, then perhaps I'll default to using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read your question correctly, you probably want to use `page.evaluate`;

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    const someVal = window._whatever.factory.producer.getContent()[1].node.value
    window._whatever.runAnotherThing(someVal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [evaluateOnNewDocument](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluateonnewdocument/) because I want to ensure my script code is ran before anything else.

For example, if looking for total-blocking-time web vitals:

```js
  const perfObserver = () => {
    // Important that you don't run for this URL.
    if (window.location.href === 'about:blank') return;

    window.totalBlockingTime = 0;

    console.log(window.location.href);
    console.log('TBT', totalBlockingTime);

    const observer = new PerformanceObserver(function (list) {
      let perfEntries = list.getEntries();
      for (const perfEntry of perfEntries) {
        let longtask = perfEntry.duration - 50
        if (longtask) console.log(perfEntry);
        totalBlockingTime += longtask;
      }
      console.log({ totalBlockingTime });
    });
    observer.observe({ type: "longtask", buffered: true });
  };


  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    devtools: false
  });

  // You can control how long you want your page running if you don't like default.
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(perfObserver);

  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/");

  // Use evaluate to gather back any state.
  const performance = await page.evaluate(() => window.totalBlockingTime);
  
  console.log(performance);

  await browser.close();
```

You can also pass arguments into the function from your parent scope. See docs link above.